# Cross domain / Cross browser , ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-browser, cross-domain

Here's the scenario,

I have a `main.js` file in `abc.com` which does `$.post("index.php")` to access contents from the `index.php` from the same domain (`abc.com`).

This works great, as it is same domain ajax call.

But now, anyone can inlucde `main.js` in their website (say domain `xyz.com`).

Now, the path `index.php` (in `$.post("index.php")`) refers to file in domain `xyz.com` (not `abc.com`). If I put an absolute path `http://www.abc.com/index.php` , this does not work in some browsers (cross domain ajax restriction)

Now,

If I put headers for allow cross domain in php file, it does not work either, fails in ie 7 and below.

p.s. I need to put content in index.php file ( not in main.js ). Also, I dont want to include a php file

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://abc.com/index.php'></script>`

and I would prefer not to add `.js` file to treat as `php` file in server ( so I can put php code in js file ).

The content is huge, I cannot do `get` request or jsonp (I think, jsonp does not allow large data)

Am I missing something ? How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) or [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) to achieve this.

I've used JSONP and am going to try CORS next week. I think CORS is still asyncronous, so that might have the edge for me. At least that's my hope...

Comment: Cors is just an apache header setup to allow access from other origins.

Comment: CORS is not working in ie7 (with hack in ie8). If I'm not wrong , I need to do post request (thats not supported in jsonp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go for `server side solution`. Read the file (i.e `index.php`) in php and save the required output to be used in a `hidden field` and on DOM ready You can use the data from that hidden field.

Comment: I cannot do that. Any website can put my `main.js` in his/her website. I dont want them to do any configurations

Answer (score 0):

A curl request on the server side should work as well.  I'd say try JSONP first, but if it wont work, go for curl request